# IOS AVPlayer is not playing http urls

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios10

I'm trying to play videos with AVPlayer using URL's in IOS 10. Videos are playing fine with HTTPS URL but, with HTTP i'm getting blank screen. I also allowed NSArbitrary Loads in plist.

Please suggest, is AV Player doesn't support HTTP or any mistakes from my side?

Here's the code i'm using

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://some_ip_addr/SampleVideo.mp4"];
objPlayerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(itemDidFinishPlaying:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:objPlayerItem];
AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithPlayerItem:objPlayerItem];
AVPlayerLayer * playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
playerLayer.frame = self.view.frame;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
[player play];
```

Here's the 
[Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zE4FC.png) and
[Plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKxxN.png)

Comment: Add this 
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL: url];
    AVPlayerItem * objPlayerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset: asset];

Comment: make a screenshot of your .plist with config

Comment: Can you show us what entries you have added to your Info.plist to enable arbitrary loads?

Comment: Not entirely sure those logs are related. Is there anything else in there? Are you 100% sure your URL is correct? Is the video you're trying to play encoded in a mobile-friendly format?

Comment: [Check this video link](http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4)

Comment: What happened to Stack Overflow....has it stop helping new developers?

Comment: @Ranganathgowda are you testing in device or simulator?

Comment: I'm testing in Simulator

Comment: @JaiDeves Did you got the solution?

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but today I as well have the same situation. AVPlayer plays video in this way:

```
- (IBAction)videoButtonPressed:(id)sender {
NSURL *videoUrl = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4"];
    AVAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:videoUrl options:nil];
    AVPlayerItem *anItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
    self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:anItem];
    [self.avPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];

    self.avPlayerView = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
    self.avPlayerView.player = self.avPlayer;
    self.avPlayerView.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view addSubview:self.avPlayerView.view];
    [self.avPlayer play];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    if (object == self.avPlayer && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        if (self.avPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Failed");
        } else if (self.avPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Ready to Play");
        } else if (self.avPlayer.status == AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Unknown");
        }
    }
}
```